# How to get the total driving distance with Google Distance Matrix API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-distancematrix-api

I have an array of lat/lng. Example:

```
[
  "14.60592,103.12081",
  "38.21146,114.86461",
  "13.73028,100.65138",
  "34.08863,108.39783",
  "57.186,14.04"
]
```

How can I calculate the overall distance from A to B and from B to C.

I trying with the Google Distance Matrix API.

Comment: Total driving distance and overall distance are most likely two different things.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: calculate distance from a  to b b to c and c to d sum that distance .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula

Answer (score 0):

If you need driving distance then you will not be able to calculate it with any formula not knowing the terrain, roads etc. For example if there is a river between those two points then the driving distance will depend on where is the closest bridge.

You can use some API that has that knowledge and can give you a real driving distance. For example you can use the Google Maps API. See e.g. Distance Matrix API:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

You can use the Google Maps API in Node with:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/googlemaps

and some more - see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/google-maps